# Can I make the index page of a web project as the login page or do I need to have a different page for login?

Tags: html, jsp

Is there any rule that I cannot use index page of my webproject as the login page for the users? Do I need to redirect it to another page? Is this anything like best practice?

Comment: If you want the login page to invalidate the session when its hit, then you want a separate page. Some applications double the login page as the logout page in that way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all there is no such rule. But if we are talking about best practice then index page (often called 'home page') should be welcome or descriptive about site  and then you can put login page link on that.

Second, You can make your login page as index page if you want to.

Comment: But isn't the home page is the first page AFTER you are logged in?

Comment: You(Or I am) are confusing it with level here. Root level is your main website and then under the website we have user so then there will be home-page in context of website and another home-page in context of user.

Answer (score -1):

No rule that I've ever heard of. It just depends on your preference. I see lots of index pages that have login forms on them.

Comment: Of course, behind the scenes, it could be that there was a forward (rather than redirect).